# Multiple Buttons for the same node reference for icons JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following code:

```
public class OrdemProducaoDialog extends Application implements Initializable{

@FXML
private VBox content;

@FXML
private Button btBuscaOrdem;

@FXML
private Button btBuscaLote;

...

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    String style = "-fx-font-size: 42px; -fx-fill: white;";

    GlyphIcon<?> searchIcon = GlyphsBuilder.create(FontAwesomeIcon.class)
            .glyph(FontAwesomeIcons.SEARCH)
            .style(style)
            .build();

    btBuscaOrdem.graphicProperty().setValue(searchIcon);
    btBuscaLote.graphicProperty().setValue(searchIcon);

}
```

The link resulting image of the code above

[image]

How can I use the same reference from one node to the two buttons so that the icon go for the two buttons?

Comment: I don't know what the `GlyphIcon` class is, but you cannot place a node into the scene graph twice. You should create two instances of the graphic and set one for each button. You may be able to let both instances of the node share the same image resource (for example, if you are using a standard `ImageView`, you can create one `Image` object and then two `ImageView` instances from the same `Image`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

As James_D already assumed: GlyphIcon is a Node.

It is part of [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/a8b32e3267a3?at=master). The class [GlyphIcon](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/a8b32e3267a3c155feb582ad80c565460a244832/src/main/java/de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphIcon.java?at=master) extends 
JavaFX [Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) and Text extends [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html) and Shape extends [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html).

#### Hierarchy

```
Node
|
-> Shape
       |
       -> Text
             |
             -> GlyphIcon
```

And in [Node's JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) is a hint

> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region,
>   etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the
>   root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from
>   its former parent.

So you are not able to set **one** GlyphIcon instance to more than **one** button's graphic.

#### Solution

You need to create for each GlyphIcon an own instance and set the size with the correct style.

```
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  private Button btBuscaOrdem;

  @FXML
  private Button btBuscaLote;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    // number of buttons
    int iconsSize = 2;
    // the glyph to set
    FontAwesomeIcon glyph = FontAwesomeIcon.SEARCH;
    /*
     * the style to set, glyph have two styleable properties:
     *
     * -glyph-size
     * -glyph-name
     */
    String style = "-fx-fill: white; -glyph-size: 42px;";
    // where the icon instances will be stored;
    GlyphIcon<?>[] icons = new GlyphIcon<?>[iconsSize];
    // create instances
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
      icons[i] = GlyphsBuilder.create(FontAwesomeIconView.class)
          .glyph(glyph)
          .style(style)
          .build();
    }

    btBuscaOrdem.setGraphic(icons[0]);
    btBuscaLote.setGraphic(icons[1]);

    // two possibilities to only show graphic
    btBuscaOrdem.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    btBuscaLote.setStyle("-fx-content-display: graphic-only;");
  }
}
```

Enjoy the buttons!